# Movie play error - nil string

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a movie in ios but i keep getting error.

My code:

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender

NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"big-buck-bunny-clip" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

}

```
- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayerController];
[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];


[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 100, 250, 163)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
//moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

}

the error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it .. i forgot to add the file in build phase ...

Comment: You should add more explicit details to make this a proper answer.